# UIViews inside a super or master UIView, display correctly in StoryBoard but shrink in the emulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I am quite new in swift programming and I am developing an app which has multiple custom views, hope some one can help me here.
The issue is that I have a scrollView, inside I have a stackView with about 20 Views inside, every view has inferred constraints and every view has a fixed height, maybe not the best practice but most of the views show correctly (had to re-do about 3 times to get here), but one of my views (around the middle of the stack) is showing correctly in my story board, but somehow it's shrinking it's subviews when launching the app, not sure if I am missing something, I have even removed all the content of these subviews and left only the main views with their heights but still I have the same issue.

To be more detailed the section that fails is a view inside the vertical stackView, it contains a view (container) which has the same leading, trailing, top and bottom as the first one. This container view, contains 5 (sub)views which have the same height each (124), and have practically the same content: a label, a texfield and a custom slider (thought the slider was ruining everything because it's custom but after removing all from the design the error still occurs).
Here is an image of how it's shown in the story board:
[views in story board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjC0j.png)

And here is how it's displayed in the emulator:
[view in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWjWx.png)

Does anybody now why can this be happening? I am not doing any layout stuff in the code only a couple of corner rounding in other views that are inside the stack view.
BTW, I also implemented this 5 slider views using a vertical stack and had the same issue, I switched and changed to simple views and separated by 10 each bottom with the next view top.

Thanks

Comment: It's a little difficult to tell from the images you posted, but likely you're missing some vertical constraints. Also, near the bottom, you show a constraint of `height = 690` which looks wrong. If you post your storyboard somewhere, we can take a look at it.

Comment: Hello @DonMag, thanks for you answer, yes I know is difficult to get a clear view and context of the error just with a couple of pictures. I will see where can I upload more context on the issue. About the 690 is the sum of the 5 views of 124 each plus the interspace. I remade everything with no success, but I was able to make it work by moving 1 out of the 20 views out of the main container, so now intead of having 1 container view and 20 views inside I have 1 container view with 19 views and 1 independent views and the design is showing correctly.